# Can a wifi network have WPA encryption, WEP cipher and OPEN authentication?

Tags: wifi, wpa2, wep

Can a wifi network have WPA encryption, WEP cipher and OPEN authentication?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is weird to say the least

- WPA supports the CCMP and TKIP ciphers
- an SSID supports either WEP or WPA/WPA2

So the answer to your question is **no**, which begs the question : in which conditions did you get the screenshot?